# Please update the Wolfram Language highlighter for this site

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, syntax-highlighting

I took the time to update the Google-prettify highlighter for Mathematica to the current version 11.0.1. The whole project can be found in my [Mathematica Source Code Highlighting](https://github.com/halirutan/Mathematica-Source-Highlighting) repository on GitHub, but the only important file that changed is

- [lang-mma.min.js](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/halirutan/Mathematica-Source-Highlighting/master/src/lang-mma.min.js) (*un-minified* source file [lang-mma.js](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/halirutan/Mathematica-Source-Highlighting/master/src/lang-mma.js))

Would StackExchange consider updating our highlighting engine for this site?

Answer (score 11):

Done, this will be live after the next build (later today).

Thank you for your continued work on this!